# Finding total number of states and transitions in UPPAAL

Tags: model-checking, uppaal

I have big UPPAAL model. I want to analyze total number of states and transitions in my model.
Is there any way to find out these things.

Thankyou and regards

Answer (score 1):

Not really. In principle the number of (concrete) states is uncountable.
Uppaal deals with symbolic states and the number of explored symbolic states may differ depending on the search order. Use `verifyta -u` to report the number of explored states.

Comment: thanku... i am using GUI uppaal. i did not find any command-line option. where should i write this command

Comment: verifyta utility is in bin-Win32 or bin-Linux. Use 'verifyta -h' for help.

Comment: thanhku Sir. while analyzing explored states using 'verifyta',  system reports some numerical value in seed. what is seed means... is it show maximum number of explored states

Comment: Seed is for random number generator (for repeatability), please ignore that.

Comment: While using command 'verifyta -u' , in order to find total states, two different states comes (1) states stored, (2)states explored. If i want to know total number number of states, should i add these two states or just consider states explored.

Comment: There is no total. Stored refers to how much is stored in memory, explored refers to performance -- how many states processed. Explored is always greater or equal than stored because some states may be explored multiple times and sometimes some states may be not stored and thus explored several times.